# grammatical role of the word "e" in Emiliano and Romagnolo languages

Tags: parts-of-speech, romance-languages, italian, conjunctions

What is grammatical role of **e** word in Emiliano and Romagnolo languages? Notice the following excerpt:

> >
>   La léngua emiliâna-rumagnōla l’é parlêda int l’Emélia-Rumâgna, int la pêrt ed sōvra dal Mêrchi (pruvîncia ed Pêṣer) **e** in Tuscâna (pruvîncia ed Mâsa-Carēra). L’a ‘s divèd in dō pêrti: l’Emigliàn **e** al Rumagnōl. A’s pèinsa che la divisiòun tr’al dō sesiòun descréti sōvra la sia sucèsa a l’inési dal Medioēv, quând i Bizantèin gvernêven la Rumâgna **e** i Longobêrd l’Emélia.

(See more examples on [the Wikipedia page](http://eml.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langua_emigli%C3%A8na-rumagn%C3%B4la))

Comment: Can you highlight the word in the excerpt?

Answer (score 4):

I don't have any direct knowledge of the language(s), but from the excerpt you provide, "e" seems to mean "and", i.e., it is a coordinating conjunction: "e in Tuscâna" (and in Tuscany), "l’Emigliàn e al Rumagnōl" (Emiliano and Romagnolo), "i Bizantèin gvernêven la Rumâgna e i Longobêrd l’Emélia" (the Byzantines ruled Romagna and the Langobards ruled Emilia)

Comment: That's exactly it. It's a conjunction. :)